# Variable in for loop not behaving as expected. [C17]

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a piece of code that would divide a set amount of money into their biggest bills constituents. Say, Input = 1200, then the code would print "[2]500 bills, [1]200 bills".

However using said Input the code would print "[2]500 bills, [2]100 bills". If I add a printf("%d",i); to see how the  i  values changes through the loop is does on a seemingly random manner; it also depends on the input given? Why?!
I can't get my head around of why this is happening.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float Input;
    scanf("%f",&Input);
    int SizeBilletes[7] = {500,200,100,50,20,10,5};
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(Input/SizeBilletes[i]>1){
            int a = floor(Input/SizeBilletes[i]);
            Input -= a*SizeBilletes[i];
            printf("[%d] en Billetes de %d\n",a,SizeBilletes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Important Notes:**

- The Input has to be a float as the user might add a value that isn't an integer (like cents or penys)
- If instead of a loop I use a ton of if statements to evaluate each size individually it works like a charm
- Using "Input %= SizeBill[i]" give me an error (was a solution given on a discord community)
- I'm **very** new to programming so apologies in advance if this is quite a simple problem.

Comment: Never ever use `float` or `double` for calculations with money. Use only integral types.

Comment: “He piled upon the whale's white hump the sum of all the general rage and hate felt by his whole race from Adam down; and then, as if his chest had been a mortar, he burst his hot heart's shell upon it.” -- Herman Melville, [On representing currency by floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Input/SizeBilletes[i]>1` with `Input / SizeBilletes[i] >= 1`

Comment: Man, this worked a charm. I feel a bit embarrassed right now, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should first use a data type that allows you to manage quantities with full precision.  Rounding with floats can be the source of problems, and with `float` valued quantities, you can have only 24 bits of precision (roughly 7 figures), while `double` doesn't seem to completely solve (as it raises the precision to 53 bits, this is around 16 figures)  The best should be to operate int the minimum quantity (let's say cents, or thousands of cents) you should use `unsigned long` 64bit quantities, and manage all quantities as multiples of that (this is full precision on around 20 figures).  Let's say you use cents as the basic unit, you can solve your problem with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

You don't need the `<math.h>` include (only if you are using functions from
the `-lm` library, like `sin()` or `fmod()`)

```
#define NELEM(_array) (sizeof (_array) / sizeof (_array)[0])
```

The macro above will tell you the size of an array by dividing the size of
the array by the size of it's first element.  As both are static values (known at compilation time) this results in a constant value that doesn't have to be calculated at runtime.

```
int main()
{
    double Input;
    scanf("%lg",&Input);
```

We use ad `double` as per your requirement, so the user can use decima quantities, but we convert those to the integer value of cents (I assume this is the smallest unit of money you are using, but you can handle other units smaller, e.g.  Movistar in Spain computes phone bills on a thousands of cent unit basis, this is 5 figures after the decimal point)

Now, the actual sizes in hour units are shown. No unit less than the values used here will be used, so no need to store them.

```
    /* conversion automatically done and
     * rounding to closest cent (except for
     * the case of rounding errors on scale
     * switching of floating point number */
    long unsigned input = Input * 100.0 + 0.5;
```

the code above converts to internal units and rounds the value to the closest integer

```
    static const int SizeBilletes[] = {
        50000,20000,10000, /* 500EUR, 200EUR, 100EUR */
        5000,2000,1000,
        500,200,100,
        50,20,10,
        5,2,1,            /* 0.05EUR, 0.02EUR, 0.01EUR */
    };
```

The names can be changed if you want to use more faimiliar names like the old spanish *duros*, or the american *dime* :)

```
    static const char * const NameBilletes[] = { /* Note/Coin names */
        "500EUR note", "200EUR note", "100EUR note",
        "50EUR note", "20EUR note", "10EUR note",
        "5EUR coin", "2EUR coin", "1EUR coin",
        "0.50EUR coin", "0.20EUR coin", "0.10EUR coin",
        "0.05EUR coin", "0.02EUR coin", "0.01EUR coin"
    };
```

We use the array size here, and don't put it explicitly on the declaration, as it will make changing things easier (if you change the lists, you have only to bother that the number or elements in the names array is the same as the number of the values array, but you don't have to change all the magic `7` quantities you have spread all over the source.

```
    printf("%lg -> ", Input);
    char *sep = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < NELEM(SizeBilletes); i++) {
        unsigned n_notes = input / SizeBilletes[i];
        input %= SizeBilletes[i];
        if (n_notes) {
            printf("%s[%d]%s",
                    sep, n_notes, NameBilletes[i]);
            sep = ", ";
        }
    } /* for */
    puts("");
} /* main */
```

This makes the computation using the integer division and the remainder, with integer values at full precision, no rounding surprises.

BTW, a final note (just joking), don't mix languages when naming variables, if you use `Size`, don't use `Billetes`, a better election should have been `NoteValue` or `ValorMoneda`, but if you were using dollars, all of those notes have the same size, but different value!!! (you will be in trouble)

A sample run of the above code will result in:

```
$ pru$$
1247.33
1247.33 -> [2]500EUR note, [1]200EUR note, [2]20EUR note, [1]5EUR coin, [1]2EUR coin, [1]0.20EUR coin, [1]0.10EUR coin, [1]0.02EUR coin, [1]0.01EUR coin
```

---

#### Note

In the final printing, I use the following statement, that avoids to use the converted value, but if the value had been result (already converted from `double` but from some other calculation already in `long` type) you could print it with:

```
    printf("%ld.%02ld", input / 100, input % 100); /* change 100 and %02d for 1000 and %03d in case you use thousands of EUR, instead */
```